# i have created a compressed folder using Poweshell to compress the log files, files are not getting moved to the compresssed folder

Tags: windows-server-2008

I need to write a powershell script which will compress all the log files using built in compression methods of windows. This is what I have so far:

```
#declare functions here
function new-zipfile {
    param ($zipfile)
    if (! $zipfile.endswith('.zip')) {$zipfile += '.zip'}
    set-content $zipfile ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
    (dir $zipfile).IsReadOnly = $false
}

#define variables here
#some strings and numbers we will need
$thismonthint = get-date -f "MM"
$prevmonthint = (get-date).addmonths(-1).tostring("MM")

$thismonthstr = get-date -f "MMM"
$prevmonthstr = (get-date).addmonths(-1).tostring("MMM")

$thisyearlongint = get-date -f "yyyy"
$thisyearshortint = get-date -f "yy"

$thislogdir = 'C:\rad\'
$thiszipfile = $thislogdir + $prevmonthstr + $thisyearlongint + '.zip'
$zipexists = test-path $thiszipfile

#start program here
#first pass, check for .zip files of previous months. if exists exit. if not exist, create empty .zip file
if (! $zipexists)
{
    echo 'zip file does not exist, creating zip file'
    new-zipfile $thiszipfile
}
else
{
    return
}

# move all log files where the month number matches the month number of the .zip file
# Jan = 01, Feb = 02, Mar =03 etc. etc.

foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $thislogdir)
{
zipfile = (New-Object -ComObject shell.application).NameSpace($thiszipfile)
            $zipfile.MoveHere($file.fullname)
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 120
Move-Item 'c:\rad\*.txt' new-zipfile

    }
```

Comment: What exactly are the problems you are facing with your approach?

Comment: felix, Another big problem is when i am running the script for the secound time, it is throwing an error stating cannnot compress a compressed file.Please help else provide me script which will compress the log files using windows buit in functionality

Comment: When iterating files using `foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $thislogdir)`, you probably want to exclude compressed files.